# How to refresh the URI content obtained from the Storage Access Framework to point to the latest version

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, google-drive-picker

I have two separate devices both running KITKAT that have obtained a URI link to the same *remote* document (from Google Drive) at around the same time using the Android Storage Access Framework, using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` while also taking persistable URI permissions.

Hereafter I perform a *modification* to the document from `Device A` (whereby I download, modify, save, and then re-upload back to the `ContentProvider`), but when I then re-download the document on `Device B` (in order to refresh it)(using the existing URI), **I end up receiving the `unmodified` version of the document**. On the side, using a desktop browser I have verified that the modification from `Device A` was successfully uploaded to the remote server.

How do I refresh and download the *modified* or in other words the *latest* document on `Device B`, using the existing URI link (the URI link that has existed on `Device B` since before the update)?

I see that there is a [refresh()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#refresh(android.net.Uri,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) method callable from the `ContentResolver`, but this was only available since API 26, and I am not sure if this is what I am looking for.

Is there a proper way to `refresh` the document on `Device B`? I do not want that the `Device B` user is required to browse through the `Picker` again to obtain an updated URI to the latest version of the same document.

Comment: If you have a document on device A and you edit it then why should it have any influence on a document on device B? What would be the connection? You have told nothing about update and download. What would be downloaded? Should not you have started with a download? You see i dont understand what goes on. Please rewrite ypur post.

Comment: `say I perform an update to the document from Device A` It is already pretty unclear what you are doing here.

Comment: `verified that the upload from Device A was successful ` You did not tell before that you were uploading something.

Comment: `when I try to download it again afterwards ` You never talked about a download before.

Comment: `How do I refresh and download the updated content on Device B using the existing URI link?` What i miss in your story is that you would need an url to download from and an uri to download to.

Comment: If i understand what you are doing then there would be no need to let the user pick again. The old uries should stay usable.

Comment: @blackapps thank you for our feedback. I updated the post and tried to be more concise.

Comment: Intetesting. Sorry, at the moment i have no Google drive so cannot check.